# Qt: Why does my custom qgraphicsview widget create error during compiling on Linux?

Tags: linux, qt

My Qt project compiled successfully on Windows, but when I was trying to compile it on Linux it gives me all kinds of errors including the one I'm asking here:

I have a custom QGraphicsView class in my project, and it's prompted from the Qt designer. When I compiled my codes on a Linux machine, it gives me errors:

```
/usr/mvl1/hy2vf/metaData/bin/ui_gtvalidation.h:55: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘myGraphicsView’ with no type

/usr/mvl1/hy2vf/metaData/bin/ui_gtvalidation.h:55: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token

/usr/mvl1/hy2vf/metaData/bin/ui_gtvalidation.h: In member function ‘void Ui_GTvalidation::setupUi(QDialog*)’:

/usr/mvl1/hy2vf/metaData/bin/ui_gtvalidation.h:173: error: ‘graphicsView’ was not declared in this scope

/usr/mvl1/hy2vf/metaData/bin/ui_gtvalidation.h:173: error: expected type-specifier before ‘myGraphicsView’

/usr/mvl1/hy2vf/metaData/bin/ui_gtvalidation.h:173: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘myGraphicsView’
```

Does anyone have had same issues? What's the solution?

Here is the part in ui_gtvalidation.h where it says the problems are. I'm actually not sure what part of my codes I should post to help, so let me know what you want to look at.

```
55:myGraphicsView *graphicsView;

173:graphicsView = new myGraphicsView(GTvalidation);
    graphicsView->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("graphicsView"));
```

myGraphicsView.h

```
#include <QtGui>

class myGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView{

public:
myGraphicsView(QWidget* parent = 0);

~myGraphicsView(void); 

protected:
//Take over the interaction
virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event);

};
```

myGraphicsView.cpp:

```
#include "myGraphicsView.h"


myGraphicsView::myGraphicsView(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent){
}

myGraphicsView::~myGraphicsView(void){
}

void myGraphicsView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event) {

setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);

// Scale the view / do the zoom
double scaleFactor = 1.15;
if(event->delta() > 0) {
    // Zoom in
    scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
} else {
    // Zooming out
    scale(1.0 / scaleFactor, 1.0 / scaleFactor);
}

// Don't call superclass handler here
// as wheel is normally used for moving scrollbars
}
```

Comment: you need to display the class myGraphicsView

Comment: Your problem is actually in your `gtvalidation.ui` file. When you promote a widget to custom class, you need to specify include header correctly. For some reason compiler cannot find specified header in Linux. The most simple reason of this could be capitalization mismatch (as Linux filesystems are case sensitive and Windows ones are not). Check header files specified in promotion settings of your form in Designer.

Comment: Thanks @PavelStrakhov, that solved the problem. However, I can not find the check mark here to mark your answer lol. Sorry, newbie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually in your `gtvalidation.ui` file. When you promote a widget to custom class, you need to specify include header correctly. For some reason compiler cannot find specified header in Linux. The most simple reason of this could be capitalization mismatch (as Linux filesystems are case sensitive and Windows ones are not). Check header files specified in promotion settings of your form in Designer.